# net use in batch file - yes to prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to script a  net use command:

```
net user UserName ReallyLongPasswordHere /add
```

When I execute this I get a prompt:

```
The password entered is longer than 14 characters.  Computers
with Windows prior to Windows 2000 will not be able to use
this account. Do you want to continue this operation? (Y/N) [Y]:
```

How can I yes thorugh this? I tried:

```
echo y| net user UserName ReallyLongPasswordHere /add
```

But that doesn't work, it says "No valid response was provided". Windows Server 2008R2 is where this is running.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have Windows Server, but try `echo. | net use ...` maybe?

Comment: See [Force “net user” command to set password longer than 14 characters](http://serverfault.com/questions/452894) where such questions are welcome and answered.

Answer (score 4):

You can add `/Y` or `/YES` to answer this prompt.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
net user MyUser MyPasswordIsReallyLong /ADD /Y
```

*(This is an undocumented feature.)*

Comment: I know this answer is old, but /Y does not work in Windows Server 2016

Comment: Strange, it works for me on 2019